# How I can know how many times a word is repeated?

Tags: haskell

I have the follow text: `"Hello world! I love this world"` and I need to know how many times the word "world" is repeated in the text. How I can do it with Haskell?

Comment: Write code. We don't do that for you. We (maybe) try help fix code that you have written.

Comment: What is so hard? You need only the logic and syntaxes. If you know the syntaxes and logic, you can write your program :) (Logic simple: Search for word, and if is found, increment a variable, simple as that)

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.List.Split(splitOneOf)

wordcount w = length . filter (==w) . splitOneOf ";.,! "

> wordcount "world" "Hello world! I love this world"
2
```

Answer (score 0):

The stupid way is to look at each position in the list and check if it's the start of `"world"`. Count up the positions that are and you're done.

```
Data.List> length . filter ("world" `isPrefixOf`) . tails $ "Hello world! I love this world"
2
```

Comment: maybe `words` instead of `tails` is ok here too (and maybe easier to the novice-eye)

Comment: @Carsten Perhaps. It depends on what behavior is desired, too. Hopefully anyone who stumbles on this and takes the time to understand the snippet  will be able to either modify it as needed for their behavior or be able to write a well-formed follow-up question.

Comment: @Carsten `words` may not work on some input like `world,world`

Comment: @klappvisor that's why I had the "maybe" in there - it's just when the question asks for words instead of prefix ...

Comment: @Carsten I just thought it would be good to mention for some user who does not know that `words` in haskell splits text by spaces, and not by any regexp or some other logic. `tails` solution also has similar issue when `world` is part of other word which should not be found...